# I am trying to make a moving object but the code isn't doing anything. I'm wondering what the problem is?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am very new to JavaScript and HTML and CSS. I have read through my code multiple times and I can't seem to figure out what makes it not work. It is not returning any errors, but it's not working as expected. I'm trying to get a square on the screen to move on the press of WASD. I got the square to appear but nothing happens when WASD is pressed. I feel like the solution must be simple but I can't figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onkeypress="move(event)">
  <style>
  #block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #555;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  </style>
  <div id="block"class="block"></div>
  <script>
  var blockX = 0;
  var blockY = 0;
  var keyPressed = 0;
  function move(event) {
    keyPressed = event.keyCode;
    if (keyPressed === 87 || 83) {
      moveY();
    }
    else if (keyPressed === 65 || 68) {
      moveX();
    }
  }
  function moveX() {
    if (keyPressed === 65) {
      blockX -= 3;
      document.getElementById("block").style.marginLeft = blockX + "px"
    }
    else if (keyPressed === 68) {
      blockX += 3
      document.getElementById("block").style.marginLeft = blockX + "px"
    }
  }
  function moveY() {
    if (keyPressed === 87) {
      blockY += 3;
      document.getElementById("block").style.marginTop = blockY + "px"
    }
    else if (keyPressed === 83) {
      blockY -= 3;
      document.getElementById("block").style.marginTop = blockY + "px"
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The pressed key check in `move` will pass all keys on the first `if`. The conditions should be like `keyPressed === 87 || keyPressed === 83`. Also, `event.keyCode` is not standard, maybe you should use the newish [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead.

Comment: You can but shouldn't use `event.keyCode`. It's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: The `keypress` event is also deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event Use `keyup` or `keydown` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the keyPressed variable like this
`(keyPressed === 87 || keyPressed === 83)`

Also, you can listen for a keydown event using the following function:

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  move(event)
});

var blockX = 0;
var blockY = 0;
var keyPressed = 0;

function move(event) {
  keyPressed = event.keyCode;
  if (keyPressed === 87 || keyPressed === 83) {
    moveY();
  } else if (keyPressed === 65 || keyPressed === 68) {
    moveX();
  }
}

function moveX() {
  if (keyPressed === 65) {
    blockX -= 3;
    document.getElementById("block").style.marginLeft = blockX + "px"
  } else if (keyPressed === 68) {
    blockX += 3
    document.getElementById("block").style.marginLeft = blockX + "px"
  }
}

function moveY() {
  if (keyPressed === 87) {
    blockY += 3;
    document.getElementById("block").style.marginTop = blockY + "px"
  } else if (keyPressed === 83) {
    blockY -= 3;
    document.getElementById("block").style.marginTop = blockY + "px"
  }
}
```

```css
#block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block" class="block"></div>
```